# Weights and Biases: Login and network errors

Tags: python, wandb

I recently installed Weights and Biases (wandb) for recording the metrics of my machine learning projects. Everything worked fine when connected to wandb cloud instance or when I used a local docker image. Now, when I tried to access my local wandb instance from over the network, I started to get API error messages. However, I also noticed that wandb was trying to access my server using port 80, instead of 8080. I installed wandb client on a new cloud server and tried to access my server from there. Still, same error message shown below.

This error happens when I use the command: `wandb login host=https://api.wandb.ai`
I have tried to delete the .netrc file where the api settings are stored and re-installed wandb. Still same error. Using wandb version 0.10.2 on Ubuntu 18.04; Also, tried downgrading to version 0.8.36, no change.
If I try the command: `wandb login --relogin`, I get the same error.

Is there some way to reset wandb so it forgets all these settings, or to resolve this issue directly?

Many thanks

Best Regards,

Adeel

```
Retry attempt failed:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1277, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1323, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1272, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1032, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 972, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 187, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 172, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f0a26b54c50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 727, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 439, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='34.71.47.117', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /graphql (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f0a26b54c50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wandb/old/retry.py", line 96, in __call__
    result = self._call_fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wandb/internal/internal_api.py", line 128, in execute
    return self.client.execute(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wandb/vendor/gql-0.2.0/gql/client.py", line 52, in execute
    result = self._get_result(document, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wandb/vendor/gql-0.2.0/gql/client.py", line 60, in _get_result
    return self.transport.execute(document, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wandb/vendor/gql-0.2.0/gql/transport/requests.py", line 38, in execute
    request = requests.post(self.url, **post_args)
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 119, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='34.71.47.117', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /graphql (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f0a26b54c50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
wandb: Network error (ConnectionError), entering retry loop. See wandb/debug-internal.log for full traceback.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/bin/wandb", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wandb/cli/cli.py", line 72, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wandb/cli/cli.py", line 212, in login
    wandb.login(relogin=relogin, key=key, anonymous=anon_mode, host=host, force=True)
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wandb/sdk/wandb_login.py", line 29, in login
    anonymous=anonymous, key=key, relogin=relogin, host=host, force=force
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wandb/sdk/wandb_login.py", line 128, in _login
    apikey.write_key(settings, key)
  File "/media/adeel/Space/AI/anaconda3/envs/tf2_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wandb/lib/apikey.py", line 223, in write_key
    raise ValueError("API key must be 40 characters long, yours was %s" % len(key))
ValueError: API key must be 40 characters long, yours was 26
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm an engineer at Weights & Biases-- would love to help get this issue resolved.

If you want to reset your settings, you can do the following:

1. Delete the appropriate entry from your `.netrc` file as you have already done.
2. Delete the `wandb/settings` file from where you are launching your scripts.

You can then visit this link: https://wandb.ai/authorize and copy your API key.

Then, run the following:

`wandb login <API_KEY>`

Once you've done this, you should be good to go. Please let me know if you still run into issues after running the steps above.

Answer (score 0):

first make sure you have the package installed with
`pip install wandb`

then use it to log in with
`wandb.login(APIKEY)`