# Wandb automatically logged into the wrong user -- why?

Tags: pycharm, wandb

I followed the usual instructions:

```
pip install wandb
wandb login
```

but then it never asked me for the user and thus when I pasted my key into the terminal when asked it was there in the `.netrc` file but it was all wrong:

```
(iit_term_synthesis) brandomiranda~ ❯
(iit_term_synthesis) brandomiranda~ ❯ wandb login
wandb: W&B API key is configured. Use `wandb login --relogin` to force relogin
(iit_term_synthesis) brandomiranda~ ❯ wandb login --relogin
wandb: Logging into wandb.ai. (Learn how to deploy a W&B server locally: https://wandb.me/wandb-server)
wandb: You can find your API key in your browser here: https://wandb.ai/authorize
wandb: Paste an API key from your profile and hit enter, or press ctrl+c to quit:
wandb: Appending key for api.wandb.ai to your netrc file: /Users/brandomiranda/.netrc
(iit_term_synthesis) brandomiranda~ ❯ cat /Users/brandomiranda/.netrc
machine api.wandb.ai
  login user
  password djkfhkjsdhfkjshdkfj...SECRET...sdhjfjhsdjkfhsdjf
```

fyi useufl command:

```
cat ~/.netrc
```

how to fix this?

---

seems my issue only happens in pycharm, when I run it in the terminal it works... :/

---

cross: https://community.wandb.ai/t/wandb-automatically-logeed-into-the-wrong-user-why/2916

Comment: yes I tried forcing a relogin, and it changes my username in the `.netrc` file to `user` :/

Comment: seems my issue only happens in pycharm, when I run it in the terminal it works... :/

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64093979/weights-and-biases-login-and-network-errors

Comment: cross: https://community.wandb.ai/t/wandb-automatically-logeed-into-the-wrong-user-why/2916

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what happened, but I would suggest [forcing a relogin](https://docs.wandb.ai/ref/cli/wandb-login)

```
wandb login --relogin
```

Comment: yes I tried it, and it changes my username in the `.netrc` file to `user` :/

Comment: seems my issue only happens in pycharm, when I run it in the terminal it works... :/

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your `.netrc` file looks right. Login in as instructed in wandb and its fine to relogin. Make sure it still looks fine. Make sure you update wandb with pip. You can set the env variable with your key too. Update pycharm. Remove all the .idea folders in your projects and start from scratch. Make sure your pycharm projs have the right path to the python interpreter form pycharm. Thats I think what worked...

```
(iit_term_synthesis) brandomiranda~/iit-term-synthesis ❯ rm -rf ../ultimate-utils/.idea
(iit_term_synthesis) brandomiranda~/iit-term-synthesis ❯ rm -rf ../iit-term-synthesis/.idea
(iit_term_synthesis) brandomiranda~/iit-term-synthesis ❯ rm -rf ../pycoq/.idea
(iit_term_synthesis) brandomiranda~/iit-term-synthesis ❯ rm -rf ../data/.idea
(iit_term_synthesis) brandomiranda~/iit-term-synthesis ❯ rm -rf ../proverbot/.idea
```

this was useful:

```
run_bash_command('pip install wandb --upgrade')
cat_file('~/.zshrc')
cat_file('~/.netrc')

wandb.init(project="proof-term-synthesis", entity="brando", name='run_name', group='expt_name')

print('success!\a')
```